# Richfaces not working without old ViewHandler?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-2

In JSF application we are using richfaces (Final.3.3.3). In pom.xml there is dependency on `jsf-api-2.0.2`, `jsf-impl-2.0.2` and `jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar`, and in faces-config.xml there is `<view-handler>` configured like this:

```
<application>
  <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

I know that in JSF2 you don't need jsf-facelets. You also don't need to configure `<view-handler>` in faces-config.xml. So I removed facelets jar and `<view-handler>` line from faces-config.xml. But when I did it, richfaces didn't work. E.g. `rich:toolBarGroup` is not shown.

There is javascript error "document.body is null" that comes from a4j javascript file.

Does richfaces need this specific `ViewHandler` from `jsf-facelets`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Richfaces 3.3.3 does not fully support all the features of JSF2 according to [This](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333andJSF20). You still need facelets. Specifically, the following is quoted from the limitations list on that page:

> RichFaces 3.3.3 does not support JSF 2 built-in facelets (VDL)
>
> Facelets 1.1.15 should still be used because of dependencies in RichFaces from the Tag Handlers classes.

Answer (score 3):

Amorfis there is no way of using Richfaces 3.3.3 without adding ViewHandler and facelet-1.1.15 jar as it does not have full support for JSF 2.0..