# Richfaces Primefaces JSF 2.0 configuration

Tags: richfaces, jsf-2, primefaces

I am currently using JSF 2.0 and Richfaces 3.3.3 and it's working fine.
Now I want to add Primfaces to it; I had added required jar but the components are not rendered is there any configuration i have to add in faces-config or web.xml.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771966/are-richfaces-and-primefaces-compatible-with-each-other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Richfaces 3.3.3 and Primefaces together. Primefaces needs JSF 2.0 features, and Richfaces 3.3.3 doesn't work with them.

Richfaces 3.3.3 needs facelets-1.1.15 and old ViewHandler, so new one is not used. Primefaces needs new ViewHandler, so it won't work.

I had similar problem: [Richfaces not working without old ViewHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3567821/121595)

Comment: Don't know :) You have to choose Richfaces 3.3.3 or Primefaces. You can't have both. Or you can try Richfaces 4.0. It works with JSF 2.0. It is not yet fully released, but there is Milestone 2 available. If you really need both, I'd go for this option.